# pipe: Bad file descriptor when running make command

Tags: python, makefile

Anyone can help me with this issue?
I am trying to run an app, whenever I run **make** in the terminal I got that error

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, python3.8 -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 8))", ...) failed.enter code here
Makefile:24: pipe: Bad file descriptor

SETUP  Creating virtualenv

FATAL  Python not found (python3.8)

make: *** [Makefile:21: .venv] Error 1
```

I've created a venv before running and installed python8.3, pip as well.

Makefile

```
PYTHON ?= python3.8
FLASK_HOST ?= 127.0.0.1
FLASK_PORT ?= 5000
VENV ?= .venv

SHELL := /bin/bash
PIP := ${VENV}/Scripts/pip
FLASK := ${VENV}/Scripts/flask
CONFIG := licmon/licmon.cfg
SERVERS := licmon/servers.cfg

.PHONY: all
all: ${VENV} config
    @printf "\033[38;5;154mSETUP\033[0m  \033[38;5;105mInstalling licmon python package\033[0m\n"
    @${PIP} install -q -e '.[dev]'

 
${VENV}:
    @printf "\033[38;5;154mSETUP\033[0m  \033[38;5;105mCreating virtualenv\033[0m\n"
ifeq (, $(shell which ${PYTHON} 2> /dev/null))
    @printf "\033[38;5;220mFATAL\033[0m  \033[38;5;196mPython not found (${PYTHON})\033[0m\n"
    @exit 1
endif
ifneq (True, $(shell ${PYTHON} -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 8))'))
    @printf "\033[38;5;220mFATAL\033[0m  \033[38;5;196mYou need at least Python 3.8\033[0m\n"
    @exit 1
endif
    @${PYTHON} -m venv --prompt licmon .venv
    @${PIP} install -q -U pip setuptools


${CONFIG}: | ${CONFIG}.example
    @printf "\033[38;5;154mSETUP\033[0m  \033[38;5;105mCreating config [\033[38;5;147m${CONFIG}\033[38;5;105m]\033[0m\n"
    @cp ${CONFIG}.example ${CONFIG}
    @printf "\033[38;5;154mSETUP\033[0m  \033[38;5;105mCreating config [\033[38;5;147m${SERVERS}\033[38;5;105m]\033[0m\n"
    @cp ${SERVERS}.example ${SERVERS}
    @sed -i.bak "s/^SECRET_KEY = None/SECRET_KEY = '$$(LC_ALL=C tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 32)'/" ${CONFIG}
    @sed -i.bak "s/^SKIP_LOGIN = False/SKIP_LOGIN = True/" ${CONFIG}
    @sed -i.bak "s/^EMAIL_BACKEND = '[^']\+'/EMAIL_BACKEND = 'licmon.vendor.django_mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'/" ${CONFIG}
    @rm -f ${CONFIG}.bak
    @printf "       \033[38;5;82mDon't forget to update the config files if needed!\033[0m\n"


.PHONY: flask-server
flask-server:
    @printf "  \033[38;5;154mRUN\033[0m  \033[38;5;75mRunning Flask dev server [\033[38;5;81m${FLASK_HOST}\033[38;5;75m:\033[38;5;81m${FLASK_PORT}\033[38;5;75m]\033[0m\n"
    @${FLASK} run -h ${FLASK_HOST} -p ${FLASK_PORT} --extra-files $(abspath licmon/licmon.cfg):$(abspath licmon/servers.cfg)


.PHONY: build
build:
    @printf "  \033[38;5;154mBUILD\033[0m  \033[38;5;176mBuilding production package\033[0m\n"
    @rm -rf build
    @source ${VENV}/bin/activate
    @${PIP} list
    @python setup.py bdist_wheel -q


.PHONY: config
config: ${CONFIG}


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @printf "\033[38;5;154mCLEAN\033[0m  \033[38;5;202mDeleting all generated files...\033[0m\n"
    @rm -rf .venv newdle.egg-info pip-wheel-metadata dist build
    @find newdle/ -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `@` to suppress echoing makefile commands until you are *sure* that the makefile is working correctly.  And even then, consider not doing so.

Also, I urge you to avoid putting ANSI escape sequences into your makefile.  They are obnoxious to read, and they will not be effective in all contexts.  Absolutely omit them from any makefile you present here, as they are not part of any minimal reproducible example unless it is asking specifically about them.

Anyway, this problem ...

> ```
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, python3.8 -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 8))", ...) failed.enter code here
> Makefile:24: pipe: Bad file descriptor
> ```

... appears to be a consequence of this problem ...

> ```
> FATAL  Python not found (python3.8)
> ```

.  The messages are ordered that way in the output because that is the order in which they are generated, reflecting a deep flaw in your approach.

GNU `make` directives, such as `ifeq`, are evaluated when the makefile is parsed, before any recipes are run.  Thus, this code ...

> ```
> ifeq (, $(shell which ${PYTHON} 2> /dev/null))
>     @printf "\033[38;5;220mFATAL\033[0m  \033[38;5;196mPython not found (${PYTHON})\033[0m\n"
>     @exit 1
> endif
> ```

... does not halt the build immediately if the requested Python interpreter is not found.  The `exit` command is part of a recipe, which isn't (yet) being run.  As a consequence, `make` proceeds to evaluate the next directive either way:

> ```
> ifneq (True, $(shell ${PYTHON} -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 8))'))
> ```

.  If indeed `${PYTHON}` was not found, then the shell command being executed fails with the error reported, but, occurring as that does inside an execution of the `$(shell)` function, that does not terminate the build.  Make decides to build the `${VENV}` target, and when executing the recipe for that target, it finally gets around to printing the "FATAL" message and executing the `@exit 1` guarded by the above `ifeq`.  That causes `make` to stop the build and report that the recipe for `.venv` (== `${VENV}`) had an error.

> I've created a venv before running and installed python8.3, pip as well.

Notwithstanding what software may or may not have been installed, whatever shell `make` uses to execute the `$(shell)` function (which it will also use to execute recipes) does not have a command `python3.8` in its executable search path.  There is not enough information provided to troubleshoot that further.

Also, `make` does not see a subdirectoy `.venv` in its working directory, for it would not otherwise be executing the recipe for the `.venv` target.  If that surprises you, then possibly it results from running `make` from the wrong working directory.  Not much more can be said about that, either.

---

Overall, I think you're trying too hard, at least on the `make` side.  I would just let the execution of `${PYTHON}` in a recipe fail if need be, having *not* suppressed command echoing.  The makefile would be easier to write, and the diagnostic output easier to interpret.